# Is it possible to modify OpenAI environments?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

There are some things that I would like to modify in the OpenAI environments. If we use the [Cartpole](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py) example then we can edit things that are in the class init function but with environments that use `Box2D` it doesn't seem to be as straightforward.

For example, consider the [BipedalWalker](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/box2d/bipedal_walker.py) environment.

In this case, how would I edit things like the `SPEED_HIP` or `SPEED_KNEE` variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can modify or create new environments in gym. The simplest (but not recommended) way is to modify the constants in your local gym installation directly, but of course that's not really nice.

A nicer way is to download the bipedal walker environment file ([from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openai/gym/master/gym/envs/box2d/bipedal_walker.py)) and save it to a file (say, `my_bipedal_walker.py`)

Then you modify the constants in the `my_bipedal_walker.py` file, and then just import it in your code (assuming you put the file in a path that is importable, or the same folder as your other code files):

```
import gym
from my_bipedal_walker import BipedalWalker
env = BipedalWalker()
```

Then you have the `env` variable being an instance of the environment, with your defined constants for the physics computation, which you can use with any RL algorithm.

An even nicer way would be making your custom environment available in the OpenAI gym registry, which you can do by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/README.md)

Comment: I'd emphasize that very last sentence a bit more. That is 100% the best way to do things.

Comment: @DennisSoemers Is that really the best way if all I'm looking to do is make some small adjustments to various attributes?

Comment: I would say its too much for a small change, easiest is to do the changes in a local copy of the file, as I mentioned.

Comment: @tryingtolearn It's the "cleanest" way, it's the way you should do things in my opinion if this is e.g. some longer-term project you're working on, or something you may eventually want to share with others / publish publicly on github / anything like that. It is technically a little bit more work though, so if you're really really sure that you don't care about how clean your solution is and are fine with a very quick "ugly" solution... then I guess it's ok to go with the `env = BipedalWalker()` approach.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I don't see any instructions at [the link above](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/README.md) to "making your custom environment available in the OpenAI gym registry".  Maybe they were removed.  Anyone know?

Comment: Ah, I think I found the [correct link here](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/docs/creating-environments.md) for instructions on how to create new environments for Gym.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the bipedal walker environment just like you can modify the cartpole environment.

All you have to do is modify the [constants for `SPEED_HIP` and `SPEED_KNEE`](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/box2d/bipedal_walker.py#L44).

If you want to change how those constants are used in the locomotion of the agent, you might also want to tweak the [`step`](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/box2d/bipedal_walker.py#L375) method.

After making changes to the code, when you instantiate the environment, the new instance will be using the modifications you made.

Comment: Thanks for your annswer. But I can't do this directly from the "env" object because the object doesn't have those attributes. Does your suggestion involve going into the file that's pip installed directly?

Comment: Yes. I am suggesting that, instead of installing the package via pip, you download the library from the github repo and require it locally.