# How to set a openai-gym environment start with a specific state not the `env.reset()`?

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Today, when I was trying to implement an rl-agent under the environment openai-gym, I found a problem that it seemed that all agents are trained from the most initial state: `env.reset()`, i.e.

```py
import gym

env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
initial_observation = env.reset()  # <-- Note
done = False

while not done:
    action = env.action_space.sample()  
    next_observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

env.close()  # close the environment
```

So it is natural that the agent can behave down the route `env.reset() -(action)-> next_state -(action)-> next_state -(action)-> ... -(action)-> done`, this is an episode. But how can an agent start from a sepecific state like a middle state, then take an action from that state? For example, I sample an experience from the replay buffer, i.e. `(s, a, r, ns, done)`, what if I want train the agent start directly from the state `ns`, and get an action with a `Q-Network`, then for an `n-step` steps forward. Something like that:

```py
import gym

env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
initial_observation = ns  # not env.reset() 
done = False

while not done:
    action = DQN(ns) 
    next_observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    # n-step later or done is true, break

env.close()  # close the environment
```

But even though I set a variable `initial_observation` as `ns`, I think the agent or the `env` will not aware it at all. How can I tell the `gym.env` that I want set the initial observation as `ns` and let the agent know the specific start state, get continue train directly from that specific observation(get start with that specific environment)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, the current implementation of most OpenAI gym envs (including the *CartPole-v0* you have used in your question) doesn't implement any mechanism to init the environment in a given state.

However, it shouldn't be too complex to modify the `CartPoleEnv.reset()` method in order to accept an optional parameter that acts as initial state.

Comment: I changed the CartPoleEnv.reset() method, but why isn't this change getting reflected when I import gym? Do I need to "source" the gym repo somehow?

Comment: Are you importing the file you have modified? I don't really understand what do you mean with "source" the gym repo, but maybe you can find some insighs here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194107/is-it-possible-to-modify-openai-environments

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use and adapt the following code to your needs, it works well and I used it in my AlphaZero implementation.

This example is for CartPole but you should be able to adapt it easily to other envs.

```
from copy import deepcopy

import gym
import numpy as np
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Dict, Box


class CartPole:
def __init__(self, config=None):
    self.env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
    self.action_space = Discrete(2)
    self.observation_space = self.env.observation_space

def reset(self):
    return self.env.reset()

def step(self, action):
    obs, rew, done, info = self.env.step(action)
    return obs, rew, done, info

def set_state(self, state):
    self.env = deepcopy(state)
    obs = np.array(list(self.env.unwrapped.state))
    return obs

def get_state(self):
    return deepcopy(self.env)

def render(self):
    self.env.render()

def close(self):
    self.env.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why a direct assignment to `env.state` is not working, is because the gym environment generated is actually a `gym.wrappers.TimeLimit` object.

To achieve what you intended, you have to also assign the `ns` value to the unwrapped environment. So, something like this should do the trick:

```
env.reset()
env.state = env.unwrapped.state = ns
```

I would you suggest you extend the CartPole environment so the reset method does what you need. Then wrap your environment yourself. e.g.

```
from gym.envs.classic_control import CartPoleEnv

class ExtendedCartPoleEnv(CartPoleEnv):
    def reset(self):
        self.state = your_very_special_method()

        self.steps_beyond_done = None
        return np.array(self.state, dtype=np.float32)

max_episode_steps = 200
env = ExtendedCartPoleEnv()
env = TimeLimit(env, max_episode_steps)
```

I've just tweaked the original method found [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/a5c0608efbadfd0a1097aaff284885be18129427/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py#L161-L165).

You can also extend the original environment to change the behavior of `self.reset` to take an argument, but this is not the standard. The wrapped environment wouldn't take the argument and then you would need to call `env.unwrapped.reset` directly. This gets ugly because then `env.step` will complain that `env.reset` has not been called. etc. There are ways to make it happen, but then again, this diverges from what a regular gym environment is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solving this issue by simply setting 'env.state' to what I wanted it to be before calling 'env.step()'. This did not work if I initialized the environment using 'gym.make()'. However, I copied the source code for the environment to another file, imported it from that, and then was able to simply set 'env.state'. You just have to make sure you don't set it to something outside of the allowed values.

```
import numpy as np
from continuous_mountain_car import Continuous_MountainCarEnv

env = Continuous_MountainCarEnv()
env.reset()

print(env.state) # Random value generated by reset

env.state = np.array([-0.53, 0]) # Set it to my own value

print(env.state) # It worked

next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(np.array([0]))

print(next_state) # The next state should be close to my value not the random one
```

I copied the continuous_mountain_car file from https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/continuous_mountain_car.py

Answer (score -1):

For gym v0.25.2 you can initiate the fixed state by specifying `seed` in `env.reset()` to get the same state whenever you reset env. It works with the Taxi-v3 environment, e.g:

```
environment.reset(seed=115)
```