# Start OpenAI gym on arbitrary initial state

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Anybody knows any OpenAI Gym environments where we can set the initial state of the game? For example, I found the MountainCarContinuous-v0 can do such thing so that we can select at which point the car starts. However, I am looking for another more complex environment. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I have answered the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74584141/4666276

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to redefine the `reset` function of the class (for example, [this](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/8e5a7ca3e6b4c88100a9550910dfb1a6ed8c5277/gym/envs/classic_control/continuous_mountain_car.py#L82)). You may want to define it such that it gets as input your desired state, something like

```
def reset(self, state):
    self.state = state
    return np.array(self.state)
```

This should work for all OpenAI gym environments. If you want to do it for other simulators, things may be different. For instance, MuJoCo allows to do something like

```
saved_state = env.sim.get_state()
env.sim.set_state(saved_state)
```

Comment: Great! this is what I am looking for. Thank you very much!